# in Mac, how to press command and option at the same time?

Tags: mac, xcode

in Xcode, many hotkeys need you to press the command+option, which fingers I should use? 
For example:

- option+CMD+left/right: to folder some code
- shift+option+CMD+left/right: to folder all method

Comment: Is your question how to physically press the keys with multiple fingers?  What is causing you problems?

Comment: I use my fingers in wrong way when tap the keyboard.

Comment: There is no wrong way if it is not uncomfortable and it works.  Is there a specific problem?

Comment: its right way only if comfort?

Comment: I'd say that would be the goal unless you are a masochist. :-)  As Demis points out, it involves some finger gymnastics.  If you have a special situation, like small or large hands and a keyboard that isn't a good size match, or arthritis and the position bothers your hands, etc., you might need to experiment.  An alternative is to try the "sticky keys" (might be under accessibility), which eliminates the need to press the awkward key combinations.  You could also look at creating shortcut keys that typically require only two keys, which don't necessarily need to be with the same hand.

Comment: I view source code with xcode, and always use two or three keys of shift/ctrl/opt/CMD with left hand fingers.If left thumb press CMD, opt key is very hard to hold. I have found no comfort way to hold alt+CMD at same time for me.

Comment: Some of these key combinations must be intended to avoid an accidental nuclear launch.  Any way to redefine the key combinations to something easier?

Comment: if view code, emacs is better. My problem is CMD+opt+ctrl+shift ,I can't escape when use Mac.

Comment: I'm assuming you use a 'short' keyboard with modifier keys only on the left side? Maybe look at an extended keyboard layout that has modifiers on both ends of the main qwerty section. e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bzFKq.png

Answer (score 1):

With your Left hand, use the Index (pointing) & 2nd finger & middle fingers to hold Option (Alt),  Command and/or Shift on left side of keyboard.

Use your Right hand to hit the other key needed, which is always only one key at a time.

You can hold down the Option/Command/Control/Shift keys for as long as you want without it doing anything - only when you hit another key (with your right hand) will the action be performed.

There's a reason they call it finger gymnastics.  Just try resetting your System Management Controller (SMC) or PRAM!

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Here's my "finger gymnastics" to hit the EMACS combo you mentioned in the comments - ⌘+⌥+⌃+⇧ ! (Control+Shift hit with one finger.)

It's possible your keyboard layout doesn't allow this.  Most Apple-compliant keyboards (and my MS Surface keyboard) will allow this.

You can still press another key with the other hand if needed.
Piano lessons may help ;^)   [I do think this whole topic is hilariously non-technical, I'm glad you asked]

[image: Finger Gynastics to hit 4 keys with one hand, haha!]

Comment: @tetsujin makes a good point - indeed you may have a non-apple keyboard in which such key combos are forced to opposite sides of the keyboard (eg. some compact Windows keyboards perhaps?). My MS Surface keyboard and any Apple-compliant keyboard have all these keys clumped together on the lower-left side, allowing you to use a single-finger to hold multiple keys at a time if needed (eg. `Control` + `Shift`, or `Option`+`Command` with only one finger).